# ASP.Net: TabContainer: TabPanel Click Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabcontainer

I am using the TabContainer in my asp.net app. It has 15 tabs (TabPanels). I would like to redirect a user to a URL when the first tab is clicked. I also need to add some querystring values to the URL.

I tried this is the code behind:

```
protected void TabContainer_ActiveTabIndexChanged()
        {
            if (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 0)
            {
                string redirectURL = "Case.aspx?Action=0&CaseId=" + lblCaseId.Text + "&ChildId=" + lblChildId.Text 

                Response.Redirect(redirectURL);
            }
        }
```

And this in the ASPX page:

```
<cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel8" runat="server" OnClientClick="TabContainer_ActiveTabIndexChanged">
```

However, it broke the page.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the provider of your tab control (prefix "cc1" )

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit

Comment: "It broke the page" is not very helpful. How did it break the page? What is is doing that it shouldn't? What isn't it doing that it should? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it in a wrong way.

> OnClientClick="TabContainer_ActiveTabIndexChanged"

This method is to run on JavaScript side, if you want to do in JavaScript write a function in JavaScript and write your logic there.

If you want server side  use

> ActiveTabChanged

And write an if condition to find which tab is active and write your logic there

Answer (score 1):

If you add the event handler in your **Tab Container** tag. I think it will do the trick (presuming your event handler is coded properly).

It should look something like this:

```
<cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server"  OnActiveTabChanged="TabContainer_ActiveTabIndexChanged">
```

Also, you will need to eliminate the `OnClientClick` from your (all) individual tabs